# Python vs. Java for embedded wireless module

Tags: java, programming-languages, python, embedded-systems

We are developing a product at work which interfaces with basic I/O and sends data to a webserver over a GPRS connection.

What i need to know before we commit to a product, is which language is more suited for this task: Java or Python? (or any language to be honest) As i said, it will run on a wireless module and open serial connections, read values, send data through GPRS connections to a webserver...

Comment: What's a wireless module?

Comment: http://www.cinterion.com/tc65t.html A Wireless module @anna :)

Comment: I think your best choice is to choose the hardware that meets your needs, then choose a programming language for it. Java or Python may not even be options at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are only choosing between the two, I would say Java. But the real tool for this kind of project is C or C++.

Any memory-managed language can kill you if it does garbage-collection. For GPRS you are looking at real-time needs, and a resource-strained environment. There's a reason all of these types of projects use C languages.

You can take a look at this comparison: 
Java to C
http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=java&lang2=gcc

Python to C
http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=python&lang2=gcc

Answer (score 1):

C will be more suit for embedded system programming, because, you can manage the memory requirement, direct access the hardware platform. Java lacks on both memory management and hardware access.

---

And, what is function of your wireless module?

Comment: to datalog values to a webserver. It would read values from a rs232 serial port and GPIO and send the data over GPRS to a webserver periodically

Answer (score 0):

The only time that I have ever done anything like that it was for an Adruino board or similar (Xilinx, whatever).  The dev kit was determined by the board manufacturer.  Kugathasan has a point with C being the most likely if you don't use a base kit of some kind.  If you are using a board that doesn't have a specific dev kit, I might look towards Android supported equipment.  If you're doing it as a USB add-on to a phone or something that might be different, but the best answer might require more detail.

Answer (score -1):

Java was invented for embedded systems.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/overview/index.html

Comment: It can be used on larger embedded systems using 32-bit microprocessors such as ARMs.  It can't be used on 8-bit or 16-bit microcontrollers which still account for the majority of embedded systems for now (this is slowly changing).